# how to convert a dictionary structure to another dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I have the below dictionary

```py
#original
data = {
    'cell_0': ['13a'], 'jam_0': ['07-08'], 'model_0': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_0': ['10'], 'output_jam_0': [''], 'time_0': [''], 'output_ot_0': [''], 'time_ot_0': [''],
    'cell_1': ['13a'], 'jam_1': ['07-08'], 'model_1': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_1': ['20'], 'output_jam_1': [''], 'time_1': [''], 'output_ot_1': [''], 'time_ot_1': [''],
    'cell_2': ['13c'], 'jam_2': ['07-08'], 'model_2': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_2': ['40'], 'output_jam_2': [''], 'time_2': [''], 'output_ot_2': [''], 'time_ot_2': [''],
    'cell_3': ['13b'], 'jam_3': ['08-09'], 'model_3': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_3': ['30'], 'output_jam_3': [''], 'time_3': [''], 'output_ot_3': [''], 'time_ot_3': [''],
    'cell_4': ['13d'], 'jam_4': ['16-17'], 'model_4': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_4': ['40'], 'output_jam_4': [''], 'time_4': [''], 'output_ot_4': [''], 'time_ot_4': [''],
    'cell_5': ['13d'], 'jam_5': ['16-17'], 'model_5': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_5': ['40'], 'output_jam_5': [''], 'time_5': [''], 'output_ot_5': [''], 'time_ot_5': [''],
    'cell_6': ['13d'], 'jam_6': ['17-18'], 'model_6': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_6': ['10'], 'output_jam_6': [''], 'time_6': [''], 'output_ot_6': [''], 'time_ot_6': [''],
    'cell_7': ['13d'], 'jam_7': ['18-19'], 'model_7': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_7': ['60'], 'output_jam_7': [''], 'time_7': [''], 'output_ot_7': [''], 'time_ot_7': [''],
}
```

I want separate my dictionary to another dictionary. 
I would like the output to be:

```py
#output
data = {
    1: {'cell_0': ['13a'], 'jam_0': ['07-08'], 'model_0': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_0': ['10'], 'output_jam_0': [''], 'time_0': [''], 'output_ot_0': [''], 'time_ot_0': ['']},
    2: {'cell_1': ['13a'], 'jam_1': ['07-08'], 'model_1': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_1': ['20'], 'output_jam_1': [''], 'time_1': [''], 'output_ot_1': [''], 'time_ot_1': ['']},
    3: {'cell_2': ['13c'], 'jam_2': ['07-08'], 'model_2': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_2': ['40'], 'output_jam_2': [''], 'time_2': [''], 'output_ot_2': [''], 'time_ot_2': ['']},
    4: {'cell_3': ['13b'], 'jam_3': ['08-09'], 'model_3': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_3': ['30'], 'output_jam_3': [''], 'time_3': [''], 'output_ot_3': [''], 'time_ot_3': ['']},
    5: {'cell_4': ['13d'], 'jam_4': ['16-17'], 'model_4': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_4': ['40'], 'output_jam_4': [''], 'time_4': [''], 'output_ot_4': [''], 'time_ot_4': ['']},
    6: {'cell_5': ['13d'], 'jam_5': ['16-17'], 'model_5': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_5': ['40'], 'output_jam_5': [''], 'time_5': [''], 'output_ot_5': [''], 'time_ot_5': ['']},
    7: {'cell_6': ['13d'], 'jam_6': ['17-18'], 'model_6': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_6': ['10'], 'output_jam_6': [''], 'time_6': [''], 'output_ot_6': [''], 'time_ot_6': ['']},
    8: {'cell_7': ['13d'], 'jam_7': ['18-19'], 'model_7': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_7': ['60'], 'output_jam_7': [''], 'time_7': [''], 'output_ot_7': [''], 'time_ot_7': ['']},
}
```

how about convert output dictionary to original

```py
#convert to original again
data = {
    'cell_0': ['13a'], 'jam_0': ['07-08'], 'model_0': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_0': ['10'], 'output_jam_0': [''], 'time_0': [''], 'output_ot_0': [''], 'time_ot_0': [''],
    'cell_1': ['13a'], 'jam_1': ['07-08'], 'model_1': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_1': ['20'], 'output_jam_1': [''], 'time_1': [''], 'output_ot_1': [''], 'time_ot_1': [''],
    'cell_2': ['13c'], 'jam_2': ['07-08'], 'model_2': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_2': ['40'], 'output_jam_2': [''], 'time_2': [''], 'output_ot_2': [''], 'time_ot_2': [''],
    'cell_3': ['13b'], 'jam_3': ['08-09'], 'model_3': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_3': ['30'], 'output_jam_3': [''], 'time_3': [''], 'output_ot_3': [''], 'time_ot_3': [''],
    'cell_4': ['13d'], 'jam_4': ['16-17'], 'model_4': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_4': ['40'], 'output_jam_4': [''], 'time_4': [''], 'output_ot_4': [''], 'time_ot_4': [''],
    'cell_5': ['13d'], 'jam_5': ['16-17'], 'model_5': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_5': ['40'], 'output_jam_5': [''], 'time_5': [''], 'output_ot_5': [''], 'time_ot_5': [''],
    'cell_6': ['13d'], 'jam_6': ['17-18'], 'model_6': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_6': ['10'], 'output_jam_6': [''], 'time_6': [''], 'output_ot_6': [''], 'time_ot_6': [''],
    'cell_7': ['13d'], 'jam_7': ['18-19'], 'model_7': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_7': ['60'], 'output_jam_7': [''], 'time_7': [''], 'output_ot_7': [''], 'time_ot_7': [''],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to use library, you can convert original dict to output dict by

```
result_1 = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    number = int(k[-1])
    if number not in result_1:
        result_1[number] = {}
    result_1[number][k] = v
```

Then convert back by

```
result_2 = {}
for v in result_1.values():
    result_2.update(v)
```

Comment: What if numbers are 2-digits? also to match with the OP's format you should change to `number = int(k[-1]) + 1`. Other than that nice answer!

Comment: I have 3 digits numbers. and I Have error, 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Dev/django_project/untitled/tes_data.py", line 24, in <module>
    number = int(k[-1])+1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'h'

Comment: if more than 1 digit, use k.split('_')[-1] instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools, re
data = {'cell_0': ['13a'], 'jam_0': ['07-08'], 'model_0': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_0': ['10'], 'output_jam_0': [''], 'time_0': [''], 'output_ot_0': [''], 'time_ot_0': [''], 'cell_1': ['13a'], 'jam_1': ['07-08'], 'model_1': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_1': ['20'], 'output_jam_1': [''], 'time_1': [''], 'output_ot_1': [''], 'time_ot_1': [''], 'cell_2': ['13c'], 'jam_2': ['07-08'], 'model_2': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_2': ['40'], 'output_jam_2': [''], 'time_2': [''], 'output_ot_2': [''], 'time_ot_2': [''], 'cell_3': ['13b'], 'jam_3': ['08-09'], 'model_3': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_3': ['30'], 'output_jam_3': [''], 'time_3': [''], 'output_ot_3': [''], 'time_ot_3': [''], 'cell_4': ['13d'], 'jam_4': ['16-17'], 'model_4': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_4': ['40'], 'output_jam_4': [''], 'time_4': [''], 'output_ot_4': [''], 'time_ot_4': [''], 'cell_5': ['13d'], 'jam_5': ['16-17'], 'model_5': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_5': ['40'], 'output_jam_5': [''], 'time_5': [''], 'output_ot_5': [''], 'time_ot_5': [''], 'cell_6': ['13d'], 'jam_6': ['17-18'], 'model_6': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_6': ['10'], 'output_jam_6': [''], 'time_6': [''], 'output_ot_6': [''], 'time_ot_6': [''], 'cell_7': ['13d'], 'jam_7': ['18-19'], 'model_7': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_7': ['60'], 'output_jam_7': [''], 'time_7': [''], 'output_ot_7': [''], 'time_ot_7': ['']}
new_data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:int(re.findall('\d+$', x[0])[0]))
r = {a+1:dict(list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(new_data, key=lambda x:int(re.findall('\d+$', x[0])[0]))}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'cell_0': ['13a'], 'jam_0': ['07-08'], 'model_0': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_0': ['10'], 'output_jam_0': [''], 'time_0': [''], 'output_ot_0': [''], 'time_ot_0': ['']}, 
 2: {'cell_1': ['13a'], 'jam_1': ['07-08'], 'model_1': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_1': ['20'], 'output_jam_1': [''], 'time_1': [''], 'output_ot_1': [''], 'time_ot_1': ['']}, 
 3: {'cell_2': ['13c'], 'jam_2': ['07-08'], 'model_2': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_2': ['40'], 'output_jam_2': [''], 'time_2': [''], 'output_ot_2': [''], 'time_ot_2': ['']}, 
 4: {'cell_3': ['13b'], 'jam_3': ['08-09'], 'model_3': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_3': ['30'], 'output_jam_3': [''], 'time_3': [''], 'output_ot_3': [''], 'time_ot_3': ['']}, 
 5: {'cell_4': ['13d'], 'jam_4': ['16-17'], 'model_4': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_4': ['40'], 'output_jam_4': [''], 'time_4': [''], 'output_ot_4': [''], 'time_ot_4': ['']}, 
 6: {'cell_5': ['13d'], 'jam_5': ['16-17'], 'model_5': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_5': ['40'], 'output_jam_5': [''], 'time_5': [''], 'output_ot_5': [''], 'time_ot_5': ['']},
 7: {'cell_6': ['13d'], 'jam_6': ['17-18'], 'model_6': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_6': ['10'], 'output_jam_6': [''], 'time_6': [''], 'output_ot_6': [''], 'time_ot_6': ['']}, 
 8: {'cell_7': ['13d'], 'jam_7': ['18-19'], 'model_7': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_7': ['60'], 'output_jam_7': [''], 'time_7': [''], 'output_ot_7': [''], 'time_ot_7': ['']}}
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Dev/django_project/untitled/tes_data.py", line 30, in <module>
    new_data = sorted(data_copy.items(), key=lambda x: int(re.findall('\d+$', x[0])[0]))
  File "C:/Dev/django_project/untitled/tes_data.py", line 30, in <lambda>
    new_data = sorted(data_copy.items(), key=lambda x: int(re.findall('\d+$', x[0])[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @rahmatzaki Please post the data that is raising that error.